# Indexing a numpy array with another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array

```
a = np.random.random((10,3))
```

and I want to use `b` to index `a`

```
# array([0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2])
b = np.random.choice(a=a.shape[1], size=a.shape[0])
```

I expect the result to be of shape `(10, )`, but I have tried the following and they all failed

```
print(a[b].shape) # (10, 3)
print(a[b,:].shape) # (10, 3)
print(a[:,b].shape) # (10, 10)
print(a[b.reshape(10,1)].shape) # (10, 1, 3)
print(a[b.reshape(1,10)].shape) # (1, 10, 3)
```

What would be correct way to index `a` in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `np.arange(a.shape[0])` as row index, with the array `b` as column index:

```
>>> a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), b].shape
(10,)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!